# Vuejs - Slots rendering nonsensical properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs-slots

I am currently having issues passing raw HTML (entity form) to a slot for syntax highlighting.

Imagine having a slot like so;

```html
<template v-slot:code-snippet>&lbrace;&lbrace; product.title &rbrace;&rbrace;</template>
```

Im receiving the error

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method 'product' is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

which is down to `&lbrace;&lbrace; product.title &rbrace;&rbrace;` - remove this and it works fine.

Is there anyway I can tell the instance to stop trying to render these "properties" as it is to be interpreted as plain text?

regards

Comment: Your code snippet is impossible to read.

Comment: Please improve your html code

Comment: @LukeSnowden Regardless of whether or not it is intentional, it is still impossible to read.  Surely there must be a better way.

Comment: OK, simply forget anything else exists within the slot apart from `&lbrace;&lbrace; product.title &rbrace;&rbrace;` as this is in an entity format and is what is causing the above error to display if that helps you to visualise it better. The reason why it's in the question is because it's the exact data I'm dealing with and to give you a notion of what I'm doing. I have already explained what is causing the issue and why it's happening, all I'm asking if if anyone knows how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted you can use `v-pre`. I would say that is the correct answer but it is worth noting that there are other ways this can be done. Perhaps if other constraints exist these could be useful.

**Hack 1:**

Move the troublesome string to a `data` property:

```html
<template v-slot:code-snippet>{{ code }}</template>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    code: '{{ product.title }}'
  }
}
```

**Hack 2:**

Wrap everything in an interpolation and throw in a bit of JS string escaping:

```html
<template v-slot:code-snippet>{{ '\u007b\u007b product.title \u007d\u007d' }}</template>
```

Depending on the circumstances this can also be adapted to work with `v-text` or `v-html` as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for taking the to to read the question and providing actual solutions to the problem, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else needing help simply wrap the content going into the slot with `<div v-pre>`;

```html
<template v-slot:code-snippet><div v-pre>{{ $component->renderCode() }}</div></template>
```

The div doesn't seem to be passed through to the slot.